# Array of ones and zeros

Tags: c#, arrays, random

How to generate array of zeros and ones in C#? Array has length *n* and exactly *k* units, where *k<=n*. Units are in *k* random positions. For example if *n=10* and *k=3* : 0010010100 or 0011010000.

Code

```
static void InitIntArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        int k=2;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = 1;
        }
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    int[] arr1 = new int[5];
    InitIntArray(arr1);

    foreach (int i in arr1)
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output is 11000.
I can not get something like 01010 or 00101.

Comment: Show some code you've written, and tell us why you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the functions of the instance of Random to get random numbers (for example, with Random.NextDouble()) and then use those numbers to decide whether each element of the array is zero or one. Otherwise your code will, as you might expect, produce the same result every time.

```
static void InitIntArray(int[] arr, int k){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        //Probability this array element is a 1
        double p = (double)k / (arr.Length-i);
        if(rnd.NextDouble() < p)
        {
            arr[i] = 1;
            k--;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```